# Extracting Text Between HTML Comments with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Using Python 3 and BeautifulSoup 4, I would like to be able to extract text from an HTML page that only delineated by a comment above it. An example:

```
<\!--UNIQUE COMMENT-->
I would like to get this text
<\!--SECOND UNIQUE COMMENT-->
I would also like to find this text
```

I have found various ways to extract a page's text or comments, but no way to do what I'm looking for. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just need to iterate through all of the available comments to see if it is one of your required entries, and then display the text for the following element as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment

html = """
<html>
<body>
<p>p tag text</p>
<!--UNIQUE COMMENT-->
I would like to get this text
<!--SECOND UNIQUE COMMENT-->
I would also like to find this text
</body>
</html>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

for comment in soup.findAll(text=lambda text:isinstance(text, Comment)):
    if comment in ['UNIQUE COMMENT', 'SECOND UNIQUE COMMENT']:
        print comment.next_element.strip()
```

This would display the following:

```
I would like to get this text
I would also like to find this text
```

Comment: I was about to do this just now. +1

Comment: Does exactly what I needed. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

An improvement to the Martin's answer - you can search for specific comments directly - no need to iterate over all the comment and then check the values - do it in one go:

```
comments_to_search_for = {'UNIQUE COMMENT', 'SECOND UNIQUE COMMENT'}
for comment in soup.find_all(text=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment) and text in comments_to_search_for):
    print(comment.next_element.strip())
```

Prints:

```
I would like to get this text
I would also like to find this text
```

Answer (score 2):

Python's`bs4` module has a [Comment](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#comments-and-other-special-strings) class. You can use that extract the comments.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment

html = """
<html>
<body>
<p>p tag text</p>
<!--UNIQUE COMMENT-->
I would like to get this text
<!--SECOND UNIQUE COMMENT-->
I would also like to find this text
</body>
</html>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
comments = soup.findAll(text=lambda text:isinstance(text, Comment))
```

This will give you the Comment elements.

```
[u'UNIQUE COMMENT', u'SECOND UNIQUE COMMENT']
```

Comment: I think the OP is trying to extract the text between the comments, rather than the comments themselves.

Comment: `I would like to get this text` -this one?

Comment: Yes, that one. I am able to extract comments just fine.