# How do I parse just html between two comments using Python 3 and Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to use Beautiful Soup 4 for a scraping project, but only want to parse the html between two specific comments, similar to this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bsoup
from bs4 import Comment    

html = """
<!-- Comment 1 -->
<p>
<a href="http://www.something.htm"><h4>Link</h4></a>
    Address: 123 1st St., NYC 10001<br />
    Schools:<br />
    School Name 1<br />
    School Name 2<br />
    School Name 3<br />
</p>
<p>
    <a href="http://www.somethingelse.htm"><h4>Link</h4></a>
    Address: 456 2st St., NYC 10001<br />
    Schools:<br />
    School Name 4<br />
    School Name 5<br />
    School Name 6<br />
</p>
<!-- Comment 2 -->
"""
```

Plan is to create a list with all the `<p>` tags between those comments (ignoring the others), and then iterate through the contents of each of those to extract the `<a>` link, address, and school name for each school.

But first I'm just trying to figure out how to limit my list of `<p>` tags to the ones within those comments

Closest I found was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34673851/extracting-text-between-html-comments-with-beautifulsoup), which is different because it only extracts first elements after specific comments, but I do assume I'll end up using the Comment class somehow.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by reading through the list of child tags for the `body` element.

Here's a start on the code.

- I have added `<html><body>` to the beginning of your HTML so that BeautifulSoup would leave your other HTML properly positioned within what it generates prior to final parsing.
- First I find the `body` element, then I identify each of this element's children and output their ordinal positions, types and representations. The output follows the code.

---

```
HTML = '''\
<html><body>
<!-- Comment 1 -->
<p>
<a href="http://www.something.htm"><h4>Link</h4></a>
    Address: 123 1st St., NYC 10001<br />
    Schools:<br />
    School Name 1<br />
    School Name 2<br />
    School Name 3<br />
</p>
<p>
    <a href="http://www.somethingelse.htm"><h4>Link</h4></a>
    Address: 456 2st St., NYC 10001<br />
    Schools:<br />
    School Name 4<br />
    School Name 5<br />
    School Name 6<br />
</p>
<!-- Comment 2 -->
</body></html>'''

import bs4

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup (HTML, 'lxml')

for c, child in enumerate(soup.find('body').children):
    print (c, type(child), '\n', child)
```

Output:

```
0 <class 'bs4.element.NavigableString'> 


1 <class 'bs4.element.Comment'> 
  Comment 1 
2 <class 'bs4.element.NavigableString'> 


3 <class 'bs4.element.Tag'> 
 <p>
<a href="http://www.something.htm"><h4>Link</h4></a>
    Address: 123 1st St., NYC 10001<br/>
    Schools:<br/>
    School Name 1<br/>
    School Name 2<br/>
    School Name 3<br/>
</p>
4 <class 'bs4.element.NavigableString'> 


5 <class 'bs4.element.Tag'> 
 <p>
<a href="http://www.somethingelse.htm"><h4>Link</h4></a>
    Address: 456 2st St., NYC 10001<br/>
    Schools:<br/>
    School Name 4<br/>
    School Name 5<br/>
    School Name 6<br/>
</p>
6 <class 'bs4.element.NavigableString'> 


7 <class 'bs4.element.Comment'> 
  Comment 2 
8 <class 'bs4.element.NavigableString'>
```

In that for-loop you would now use an `if` (or whatever method you choose) to decide what type of element you are dealing with and then act accordingly. For instance, the appearance of an 'bs4.element.Comment'> with a 'Comment 1' content would indicate 'start processing', with 'Comment 2', 'stop processing'. The appearance of `'bs4.element.Tag'` with a content of `<p>` would indicate the need for you to descend a level and look for the children of the `p` tag. And so on.

Tedious but not difficult.

Answer (score -1):

Personally I would use Scrapy instead to do this as it would be easier to get just those from either their div tags or set an ID or class for the paragraph tag etc.
Here is an example of some code I put together from there documentation for scrapping from a quotes website. I hope this helps.

Install: pip install scrapy

```
import scrapy, sys, re, json
class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'Quotes'
    start_urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/']

    def parse(self, response):
        for quote in response.css('div.caption'):
            yield {
                    'text': quote.css('a.title::text').extract_first(),
                    'author': quote.xpath('div.snippet::text').extract_first()
                    }

        next_page = response.css('li.next a::attr("href")').extract_first()
        if next_page is not None:
            yield response.follow(next_page, self.parse)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply HolySaboTooth.  I don't know Scrapy, but the problem I'm trying to get around is that the page in question isn't ideally structured for scraping.  If it were set up nicely with classified divs, IDs, and list structures, I could use bs4 more easily.