# BeautifulSoup doesn't read html

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I managed to get requests to work when calling a url with specific headers, and the pages html prints when I call r.content.

```
url = 'http://patft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO1&Sect2=HITOFF&d=PALL&p=1&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsrchnum.htm&r=1&f=G&l=50&s1=9854726.PN.&OS=PN/9854726&RS=PN/9854726'
HEADERS = { 'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:63.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/63.0"} 

r = requests.get(url, headers = HEADERS)
r = r.content
```

The output is as expected (this is a shortened version since I don't want to spam the entire html):

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<BASE target="_top">
<TITLE>United States Patent: 9854726</TITLE></HEAD>
<!-BUF1=9854726
BUF7=2018
BUF8=48007
BUF9=/1/
BUF51=9
-->...
```

However, when I pass it into BeautifulSoup

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r)
print soup.prettify()
```

it only prints out:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <base target="_top" />
  <title>
   United States Patent: 9854726
  </title>
 </head>
</html>
```

It doesn't print out the full html. I was wondering if there were any quick fixes for this? I have tried encoding the requests in UTF-8 but that hasn't worked. I have also tried using r.text instead of r.content but to no avail.

I know the USPO is an old website, so if there aren't any easy solutions than I'm going to try to parse it with regex.

Edit: I just figured it out. The problem was that the output of the BeautifulSoup wasn't being formatted properly. I used regex to delete it and join it back with the original html and it worked! Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML file is malformed (intentionally or unintentionally). It uses `"<!-"` to start a comment, instead of `"<!--"`, and BS fails to recognize that comment. As a quick fix, replace the incorrect tag opener with a correct one:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.replace("<!-", "<!--"))
print(soup.prettify())
#<html>
# <head>
#  <base target="_top"/>
#  <title>
#   United States Patent: 9854726
#  </title>
# </head>
# <!--BUF1=9854726
#BUF7=2018
#BUF8=48007
#BUF9=/1/
#BUF51=9-->
#</html>
```

You can follow up with the [answers to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34673851/extracting-text-between-html-comments-with-beautifulsoup) to find out how to extract comments, e.g.:

```
soup.findAll(text=lambda text: isinstance(text, bs4.Comment))
#['BUF1=9854726\nBUF7=2018\nBUF8=48007\nBUF9=/1/\nBUF51=9']
```

Comment: This solution was better and more concise than the one I found. Thank you!