# Python Attribute Error: "NoneType object has no attribute find_all" for one table but not the other

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape MLB data from https://www.baseball-reference.com/leagues/MLB/2019.shtml. On the page there are several data tables, specifically I am interested in the batting and pitching statistics. I can successfully pull data from the batting table and put it into a dataframe but the error comes when I try to pull from the pitching table, even though the formatting is basically identical:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import time
import requests

for year in range(2018, 2020):

   url = "https://www.baseball-reference.com/leagues/MLB/{}.shtml".format(year)
   headers = {'user-agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686) Gecko/20071127 Firefox/2.0.0.11"}
   page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
   soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

   batting_table = soup.find("div", attrs={"id": "div_teams_standard_batting"})
   pitching_table = soup.find("div", attrs={"id": "div_teams_standard_pitching"})
```

I am 100% sure that HTML references are correct. batting_table is fine, but pitching_table is "NoneType". I understand that some issues can be due to the structure of the html page itself, but would that be possible in this case?

Not sure if this is useful but I use those tables in these functions to which I pass the specific stat that I want to pull from each team, then puts it in a list. This is where I use "find_all" and the error comes up:

```
def batting_stats(bstat):
    tables = batting_table.find_all("td", attrs={"data-stat": bstat})

    b_stats = []
    for table in tables:
        b_stat = table.text
        b_stat = float(b_stat)
        b_stats.append(b_stat)

        b_stats = b_stats[:-2] #exclude total and average

    return b_stats


def pitching_stats(pstat):
    tables = pitching_table.find_all("td", attrs={"data-stat": pstat})

    p_stats = []
    for table in tables:
       p_stat = table.text
       p_stat = float(p_stat)
       p_stats.append(p_stat)

    p_stats = p_stats[:-2]

    return p_stats
```

I hope that its not just a small typo on my part that I overlooked, that would be extremely frustrating.

Thank you all for the help, in advance.

**EDIT:** So thanks to Dainius I was able to find a solution! I didn't do exactly what was suggested in the link they provided, but it helped me realize that for some reason the pitching table was commented in the HTML, which wasn't obvious when inspecting the webpage so I was confused by Dainius' reply.

[What Inspect shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pATS2.png)

I didn't realize until I actually printed the "soup" and finally saw what they meant. After a quick search of how to extract comments from the HTML the solution was just adding two lines of code:

```
comments = soup.find_all(text=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment))
pitching_html = comments[19]
pitching_table = BeautifulSoup(pitching_html, 'lxml')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see the `div_teams_standard_pitching` id is inside a comment. You need to parse the text of the source code to retrieve the part you need. Because you use `BeautifulSoup` I think this solution should help.

P.S you will need to make another Selector to parse the data, because it will come as text.

[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34673851/extracting-text-between-html-comments-with-beautifulsoup)

Comment: Hmmm, I see what you mean because there's that large block that is commented, but underneath that comment the actual code is there so is that really the issue? I'm not well versed in HTML so please excuse me.

Comment: All of the commented HTML is not present in BeautifulSoup selector. You need to get the html as text and then create a selector out of it. The Martin Evans solution should work just fine.